# Glob pattern works in shell command but not in Perl backticks

Tags: bash, perl, glob

I have 3 files in 3 different directories and I need to printout only files from DIR 1 and 2

```
1 /tmp/CDE/fileA.log
2 /tmp/CFGH/fileB.log
3 /tmp/CILM_NO/fileC.log
```

if I run from bash `/bin/ls /tmp/C{[A-Z][A-Z],[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]}/*.log` it works and I get:

```
/tmp/CDE/fileA.log  /tmp/CFGH/fileB.log
```

if I run ls bash command from script perl:

```
$cmd=`/bin/ls /tmp/C{[A-Z][A-Z],[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]}/*.log`;
chomp($cmd);
print "$cmd\n";
```

I receive:

```
/bin/ls: cannot access /tmp/C{[A-Z][A-Z],[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]}/*.log: No such file or directory
```

It looks I need to escape `\{ or \, or \}` but got the same output and it does not work
I also tried using quote instead of escaping but still got same error output
It's not a matter of permission, script is 777

Can't sort of it.

Comment: I created the files and the Perl script outputs them for me.

Comment: Also note you're not using a regular expression, but a glob with brace expansion. Maybe the shell your installation of Perl runs doesn't support it?

Comment: Use the Perl glob instead of a shell perhaps. `my @files = glob("/tmp/C{[a-z][a-z],[a-z][a-z][a-z]}")`

Comment: Using `glob` also happily avoids the issues with [parsing the output of ls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 3):

(not an answer, an explanation)

### In your shell

```bash
ls /tmp/C{[A-Z][A-Z],[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]}/*.log
```

That uses bash [Brace Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion). Bash will expand that to

```bash
ls /tmp/C[A-Z][A-Z]/*.log /tmp/C[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]/*.log
```

And *then* do [Filename Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion)

### in perl

```perl
$cmd=`/bin/ls /tmp/C{[A-Z][A-Z],[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]}/*.log`;
```

The backticks will call out to **/bin/sh** not **bash**, so the brace expansion *will not happen*